# iOS 7: Divide screen in x elements of same size, which are organized horizontally side by side

Tags: ios, ios7, uiview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I want to have seven items of same size on the screen side by side. My code does work on iOS 8 but not on iOS 7.

Here is my code:

```
View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;

UILabel label1 = new UILabel ();
UILabel label2 = new UILabel ();
UILabel label3 = new UILabel ();
UILabel label4 = new UILabel ();
UILabel label5 = new UILabel ();
UILabel label6 = new UILabel ();
UILabel label0 = new UILabel ();

label1.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
label2.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
label3.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
label4.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
label5.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
label6.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
label0.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

UIView container1 = new UIView ();
container1.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Yellow;
container1.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
container1.AddSubview (label1);

UIView container2 = new UIView ();
container2.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
container2.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
container2.AddSubview (label2);

UIView container3 = new UIView ();
container3.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
container3.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
container3.AddSubview (label3);

UIView container4 = new UIView ();
container4.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
container4.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
container4.AddSubview (label4);

UIView container5 = new UIView ();
container5.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
container5.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
container5.AddSubview (label5);

UIView container6 = new UIView ();
container6.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Brown;
container6.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
container6.AddSubview (label6);

UIView container0 = new UIView ();
container0.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Orange;
container0.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
container0.AddSubview (label0);

View.AddSubviews (new UIView[] {
    container1, container2, container3, container4, container5, container6, container0
});

NSMutableDictionary viewsDictionary = new NSMutableDictionary ();
viewsDictionary ["container1"] = container1;
viewsDictionary ["container2"] = container2;
viewsDictionary ["container3"] = container3;
viewsDictionary ["container4"] = container4;
viewsDictionary ["container5"] = container5;
viewsDictionary ["container6"] = container6;
viewsDictionary ["container0"] = container0;

viewsDictionary ["label1"] = label1;
viewsDictionary ["label2"] = label2;
viewsDictionary ["label3"] = label3;
viewsDictionary ["label4"] = label4;
viewsDictionary ["label5"] = label5;
viewsDictionary ["label6"] = label6;
viewsDictionary ["label0"] = label0;

View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[label1]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[label2]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[label3]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[label4]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[label5]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[label6]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[label0]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));

View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("H:|[label1]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("H:|[label2]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("H:|[label3]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("H:|[label4]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("H:|[label5]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("H:|[label6]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("H:|[label0]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));

View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[container1]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[container2]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[container3]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[container4]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[container5]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[container6]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints (NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat ("V:|[container0]|", (NSLayoutFormatOptions)0, null, viewsDictionary));
View.AddConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.FromVisualFormat("H:|-0-[container1][container2(==container1)][container3(==container1)][container4(==container1)][container5(==container1)][container6(==container1)][container0(==container1)]-0-|",(NSLayoutFormatOptions)0,null,viewsDictionary));
```

The code is in C#, but it shouldn't bother you. You should be able to read the visual format language. As you can see I have seven `UIView` with a label on it. Without the label the code is working fine on iOS 7. The effect occurs on iPhone and iPad:

[image: see the black bar at the right side]

As you can see there is a black bar on the right side. This is the error introduced (perhaps rounding issue?). There should be no black space at all.

I tried to calculate the sizes for the views in `layoutSubviews` and `updateConstraints`, but I never got it working without other errors.

How are the constraints are correctly set up for iOS 7? It should be clear that this should work on every orientation.

**Edit:**

The screen of the iPad has in landscape orientation a width of 1024 points. If you divide this through seven you get 146,2857. So if you take the width of 146 for the first six elements the seventh element should get a width of 148. The problem now is that my constraints define that all views should get the same width, which is not possible. The black bar is from the superview (UIView where all my views were added to) and consists of the remaining two points. This only happens on iOS 7 and if I add labels to the container. I also tried to set up a spacer element but I don't get it managed that the spacer element get the remaining width of two points.

**Edit 2:**

`recursiveDescription` in `viewDidAppear`:

```
<UIWindow: 0x7b5f2f60; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7b5f3160>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7b5f2cd0>>
   | <UIView: 0x7b4faf40; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b4fa800>>
   |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7b4fafa0; frame = (0 0; 0 20); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b4fb050>>
   |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7b4fb280; frame = (0 768; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b4fb370>>
   |    | <UIView: 0x7b4196e0; frame = (0 0; 146 768); layer = <CALayer: 0x7b4195e0>>
   |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7b41bf10; frame = (0 0; 146 768); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b4fb6d0>>
   |    | <UIView: 0x7b4192c0; frame = (146 0; 146 768); layer = <CALayer: 0x7b4190b0>>
   |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7b41a1d0; frame = (0 0; 146 768); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b41a1a0>>
   |    | <UIView: 0x7b4189e0; frame = (292 0; 146 768); layer = <CALayer: 0x7b418e60>>
   |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7b419ff0; frame = (0 0; 146 768); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b419fc0>>
   |    | <UIView: 0x7b418570; frame = (438 0; 146 768); layer = <CALayer: 0x7b4184f0>>
   |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7b419e10; frame = (0 0; 146 768); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b419de0>>
   |    | <UIView: 0x7b4186c0; frame = (584 0; 146 768); layer = <CALayer: 0x7b418230>>
   |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7b419c30; frame = (0 0; 146 768); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b419c00>>
   |    | <UIView: 0x7b418050; frame = (730 0; 146 768); layer = <CALayer: 0x7b4180b0>>
   |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7b419a50; frame = (0 0; 146 768); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b419a20>>
   |    | <UIView: 0x7b417d70; frame = (876 0; 146 768); layer = <CALayer: 0x7b417dd0>>
   |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7b419870; frame = (0 0; 146 768); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7b419840>>
```

As one can see every view has the width of 146 points. What happens with the remaining 2 points? How should one deal with that?

**Possible Solution?**

Now I put the whole thing into a subview, because my real project uses that as subview and I got it working for the view controller but not subview (many tries). First I had the same problems, but when I set the constraints for the *container* after the `UILabel` constraints iOS now can render it correctly. The code is nearly identical to the above code. Don't know if I can call this solution because I can't believe it.

**The order of adding constraints in the same method seems to play an important role!**

Comment: This should correctly work for ios7 as well. Can you please post an image about how does it look in ios7?

Comment: @jarora: The image posted is for iOS 7. You have to open the image in full size and look for the white bar on the right. Perhaps I change the code to have a black background for the `UIView` so that you see it better.

Comment: use visual debuging, maybe this black bar is a superview

Comment: @MaciekWrocław: I'm afraid the visual debugger is only available in Xcode. Because I'm using another IDE (Xamarin) this is not possible or I don't know how. I edited my question where I describe the cause of the visual problem.

Comment: Please try this 
H:|[container1][container2(==container1)][container3(==container1)][container4(==container1)][container5(==container1)][container6(==container1)][container0(==container1@999)]|

Comment: @jarora: I still get the black bar on the right side.

Comment: Can you print your main views recursiveDescription & share the findings here? That would clear the picture. 
Try [View recursiveDescription] in the debugger

Comment: @jarora: I've edited my question for this.

Comment: It is a rounding issue indeed. You could use this code, i will post an answer if this works.
 H:|[container1][container2(==container1)][container3(==container1)][container4(=‌​=container1)][container5(==container1)][container6(==container1)][container0(>=co‌​ntainer1)]|

Comment: @jarora: Nope still the same result. The interesint point is that despite the rounding issue it sometimes does work and sometimes not. E.g on iPad 2 in portrait orientation there should also be the issue, but it isn't. Don't know how this behaves in a more complex project though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed some problems, but they appeared on other side again. Now I switched to a completely new approach: `UICollectionView`. There are also some flaws here (you have to call manually `invalidateLayout` sometimes, but I get used to handle that), but the only one which was able to not destroy the complete layout on iOS 7. I used a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, where I calculate the sizes by myself. I divide the screen by 7 (including rounding) and for the last element I use the remaining space. Because the layout is now exact, I have no rounding issues or whatsoever.

Now I can divide my screen in seven tiles without problems! There is now some overhead, but the only way to workaround the bugs in iOS 7.